# Simple Lens Jquery não funciona no IE e Edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, zoom, microsoft-edge

Estou utilizando o simpleLens porém o mesmo não está funcionando no IE e no Edge.

O zoom não aparece e as imagens não trocam ao passar o mouse.

Já tentei mudar diversas partes porém não funciona.

```js
(function(a){a.fn.simpleGallery=function(d){var b=a.extend({},a.fn.simpleGallery.defaults,d);if(0>=this.length)return window.console&&console.log("There are no thumbnails in the gallery"),!1;this.each(function(){a("<img>").src=a(this).attr("rel")});a(this).on(b.show_event,function(){var c=a(this).parents(b.thumbnail_anchor),d=c.attr(b.big_image_attr),c=c.attr(b.lens_image_attr),e=a(this).parents(b.gallery_container).find(b.big_image_container),g=a("<img>",{src:b.loading_image});e.html(g);var f=a("<a>").attr("data-lens-image",
c).addClass(b.parent_anchor_class),h=a("<img>").load(function(){h.appendTo(f);e.html(f)}).attr("src",d).addClass(b.big_image_class)});return this};a.fn.simpleGallery.ver=function(){return"simpleGallery-1.0.1"};a.fn.simpleGallery.defaults={thumbnail_anchor:".simpleLens-thumbnail-wrapper",big_image_class:"simpleLens-big-image",lens_image_attr:"data-lens-image",big_image_attr:"data-big-image",parent_anchor_class:"simpleLens-lens-image",gallery_container:".simpleLens-gallery-container",big_image_container:".simpleLens-big-image-container",
loading_image:"images/loading.gif",show_event:"mouseenter"}})(jQuery);


(function(c){function f(c){window.console&&console.log(c)}c.fn.simpleLens=function(l){var d=c.extend({},c.fn.simpleLens.defaults,l),h={init:function(a){this.height=a.height();this.width=a.width();this.offset=a.offset();this.position=a.position();this.calc_image_limits()},calc_image_limits:function(){this.limits={x_left:this.position.left,x_right:this.position.left+this.width,y_top:this.position.top,y_bottom:this.position.top+this.height}},calc_view_position:function(a){return{org_x:a.pageX-this.offset.left,
org_y:a.pageY-this.offset.top}}},e={init:function(a,b,c,d){this.parent_anchor=a;this.lens_container=b;this.ratio=c;this.cursor_position={top:0,left:0};this.calc_cursor_size();this.insert_cursor(d.org_x,d.org_y)},destroy:function(){c("."+d.cursor_class).remove()},calc_cursor_size:function(){this.cursor_height=this.lens_container.height()/this.ratio.x;this.cursor_width=this.lens_container.width()/this.ratio.y;this.height_center=this.cursor_height/2;this.width_center=this.cursor_width/2},update_cursor_position:function(a,
b){var c=b-this.height_center,d=b+this.height_center,e=a-this.width_center,f=a+this.width_center,g=h.limits;parseFloat(g.y_top)>parseFloat(c)?c=g.y_top:parseFloat(d)>parseFloat(g.y_bottom)&&(c=g.y_bottom-this.cursor_height);parseFloat(g.x_left)>parseFloat(e)?e=g.x_left:parseFloat(f)>parseFloat(g.x_right)&&(e=g.x_right-this.cursor_width);this.cursor_position={top:c,left:e,center_top:c+this.height_center,center_left:e+this.width_center};void 0!==this.cursor&&this.cursor.css(this.cursor_position)},insert_cursor:function(a,
b){this.cursor=c("<div>",{"class":d.cursor_class});this.cursor.css({height:this.cursor_height+"px",width:this.cursor_width+"px"});this.cursor.appendTo(this.parent_anchor);return this.update_cursor_position(a,b)}},k={init:function(a){this.parent_anchor=a;this.parent_div=a.parent(d.parent_class);this.lens_image_url=a.attr(d.lens_image_attr);this.lens_container=c("<div>",{"class":d.lens_class});this.lens_image=c("<img>");h.init(a.find(d.big_image_class));void 0===this.lens_image_url&&(f("Cannot find lens image. URL: "+
this.lens_image_url),f(that),f(a),f(lens_image_url))},update_lens_position:function(a){this.lens_image.css({top:a.top,left:a.left})},calc_lens_position:function(a){return{left:-1*(a.center_left*this.ratio.x-this.container.width),top:-1*(a.center_top*this.ratio.y-this.container.height)}},lens_event_bind:function(){var a=this;this.parent_anchor.mousemove(function(b){b=h.calc_view_position(b);e.update_cursor_position(b.org_x,b.org_y);a.update_lens_position(a.calc_lens_position(e.cursor_position,a.ratio,
a.container))})},lens_event_unbind:function(){void 0!==this.parent_anchor&&this.parent_anchor.unbind("mousemove")},destroy:function(){e.destroy();void 0!==this.lens_container&&0<this.lens_container.length&&(c("."+d.lens_class).remove(),this.lens_event_unbind())},load:function(a){var b=this;this.lens_container.appendTo(this.parent_div);var f=this.lens_container.height()/2-25,f=c("<img>",{src:d.loading_image}).css("margin-top",f);this.lens_container.html(f);this.lens_image.load(function(){b.lens_container.html(b.lens_image);
b.container={width:b.lens_container.width()/2,height:b.lens_container.height()/2};b.img_size={width:b.lens_image.width(),height:b.lens_image.height()};b.ratio={y:b.lens_image.height()/h.height,x:b.lens_image.width()/h.width};var c=h.calc_view_position(a);e.init(b.parent_anchor,b.lens_container,b.ratio,c);b.update_lens_position(b.calc_lens_position(e.cursor_position));b.lens_event_bind()}).attr("src",this.lens_image_url)}};c(this).parents(d.parent_class).on(d.open_lens_event,d.anchor_parent_class,
function(a){var b=c(this);k.init(b);k.load(a)});c(this).parents(d.parent_class).on("mouseleave",d.anchor_parent_class,function(){k.destroy()})};c.fn.simpleLens.ver=function(){return"simpleLens-1.0.1"};c.fn.simpleLens.defaults={anchor_parent_class:".simpleLens-lens-image",lens_image_attr:"data-lens-image",big_image_class:".simpleLens-big-image",parent_class:".simpleLens-big-image-container",lens_class:"simpleLens-lens-element",cursor_class:"simpleLens-mouse-cursor",loading_image:"images/loading.gif",
open_lens_event:"mouseenter"}})(jQuery);



    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#demo-1 .simpleLens-thumbnails-container img').simpleGallery({
            loading_image: 'images/loading.gif'
        });

        $('#demo-1 .simpleLens-big-image').simpleLens({
            loading_image: 'images/loading.gif'
        });
    });
```

```css
.simpleLens-container{ transition: all 0.5s;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
         height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
      min-height: 350px;
}

.simpleLens-big-image-container {
    display: table-cell;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
 position:relative;
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-radius: 20px;
  

}

.simpleLens-big-image-container img{ border-radius: 20px; overflow: hidden;}


.simpleLens-thumbnails-container{ }
.simpleLens-thumbnail-wrapper a{  }
.simpleLens-thumbnail-wrapper img{  padding: 3px;  transition: all 0.5s; width: 50px; border: 1px solid #DDD; border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden; }
.simpleLens-thumbnail-wrapper img:hover{ border: 1px solid #FCC446;}
.simpleLens-big-image {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.simpleLens-lens-image {
    height: auto !important;
    width: 350px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow:none;
    float:none;
    position:relative;
}

.simpleLens-mouse-cursor{
 background-color:#CCC;
 opacity:0.2;
 filter: alpha(opacity = 10);
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 border-radius: 20px;
 border:1px solid #999;
 box-shadow:0 0 1px 1px #999;
 cursor:none;

}

.simpleLens-lens-element {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #DDD;
    height: 500px;
    left: 105%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 500px;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.simpleLens-lens-element img{
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:auto !important;
    max-width:none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="simpleLens-gallery-container" id="demo-1">
        <div class="simpleLens-container">
            <div class="simpleLens-big-image-container">
                <a class="simpleLens-lens-image" data-lens-image="images/large/image1.jpg">
                    <img src="images/small/image1.jpg" class="simpleLens-big-image">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="simpleLens-thumbnails-container">
            <a href="#" class="simpleLens-thumbnail-wrapper"
               data-lens-image="images/large/image1.jpg"
               data-big-image="images/small/image1.jpg">
                <img src="images/thumbs/image1.jpg">
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="simpleLens-thumbnail-wrapper"
               data-lens-image="images/large/image2.jpg"
               data-big-image="images/small/image2.jpg">
                <img src="images/thumbs/image2.jpg">
            </a>

            <a href="#" class="simpleLens-thumbnail-wrapper"
               data-lens-image="images/large/image3.jpg"
               data-big-image="images/small/image3.jpg">
                <img src="images/thumbs/image3.jpg">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Qual versão do IE?

Comment: Nenhuma, testei do 11 ao 8 e o edge, nenhum funciona, chrome e firefox ok!

Comment: Resolvi o problema!
Eu estava utilizando o Jquery 1.7 e pro algum motivo o IE não estava lendo ele, troquei para a versão 2.1 e funcionou perfeitamente.

Porém ainda não entendo o motivo do conflito de versão apenas no IE e EDGE.